# Dynamically creating table rows and columns form MySQL database not output rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a script that would make a table in sort of a matrix based on user saved data in a MySQL database. In this example the sample information would be indicated in rows and the various analyses of each sample will be made in columns.

The example below creates the columns successfully, however the rows are completely omitted. Can anyone please provide a explenation and perhaps a solution to why the rows are not created? No errors are given, the rows are simply not shown.

```
 if (isset($_GET['display_full_results'])) {

        require 'dbh.php';

        $order_id = $_GET['display_full_results'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND micro_analysis!='';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



        $micro_analysis = '';
        while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $micro_analysis .= $input['micro_analysis'] . ',';
        }
        $micro_analysis_arr = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis)));



        $output = '';

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $output .= '        
            <thead>
            <tr>';

            foreach ($micro_analysis_arr as $row1) {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row1"; 
                $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $input2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);

                $output .= '
                <th colspan="1"><th>
                <th>'.$input2['m_analysis'].'</th>';
            }

            $output .= '</tr>                           
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $output .= '
                <tr> 
                <td>'.$row['env_sam_id'].'</td> 
                <td><input>Empty</td>       
                <td><input>Empty</td>           
                </tr>';
            }

            $output .= '</tbody>';
        }

        echo $output;

    }
```

Comment: You're doing extra work here. You can assign the values of `micro_analysis` directly to an array, then run it through the unique and filter functions.  In `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {`, you've already retrieved all of the results, you'll have to use [`data_seek`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to reset the search back to 0. Or you can just assign it to an array in the first place, and go through that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it really has data in it? use `print_r($result)` because it could be your query. if it shows an empty array then you should use `print($sql)` to get query then paste it on phpmyadmin to check if your query is right.

Comment: The query is correct, it stops making rows once the `foreach` loop is added in the code.